# Edit style of "index of /"

Tags: apache, fileserver

I want to make a home file server and I did not want to use some custom os or something, I wanted it to be coded by myself. So I have got the files on my hard drive on the server and I know how to download them, but it is not the best way. Basically I href them using "" but that's not very nice. Another thing I found out is that if I only type the directory, in this case "192.168.1.77/files" I get all the files listed, awesome! Just a problem, I don't know how to style it. Any help is truly appreciated!

Comment: check this https://css-tricks.com/styling-a-server-generated-file-directory/

Comment: Dude you're an angel!